# Are VS code keybindings available for IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm used to VS code shortcuts, is there anything way I can import vscode shortcuts for IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: Any update about that ?

Comment: I'd like to have them too. Starred this question hoping someone implements a keymap and adds an answer.

Comment: I've created an issue in youtrack https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192008 maybe we get a response

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Intellij officially launched the plugin [VSCode Keymap](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12062-vscode-keymap/) for IntelliJ IDEs

You can download it or add by going to Settings > Plugins and searching for VS Code

[image: Plugin Settings Screenshot]

After installing enable keymap in `settings > Keymap`
[image: IntelliJ enable VSCode keymap]

Comment: I tried to copy that file to %APPDATA%\User\.IntelliJIdea2018.3\config\keymaps as suggested in the Jetbrains documentation, but I can not find it in my keymaps dropdown to activate. How do import this keymap correctly?

Comment: You can just goto IntelliJ idea > settings > Plugins > search for vs code and install there

Comment: Thank you. I ended up creating this folder and copying the xml file from the github repo there. It worked, but wasn`t a convenient way.

Comment: Don't forget to set it in `settings>keymap` https://stackoverflow.com/a/74193549/1454173

Answer (score 30):

In my case,
**VScode plugin** was already installed.
So I just changed default keymap(windows) to vscode by going through:

> **settings** -> **keymap** -> updated keymap selection to **vscode**.
> [image]

hope it helps someone.